# Launching launcher activity from pending intent in notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent, flags

If my launcher activity A is now running.

and some activities are on top of activity A.

for example here's my backstack A B C

I need when pressing on notification to launch A, to clear A B C and then open A, or close B and C and resume A through onNewIntent

I tried adding some flags but nothing helped!

```
 private void push(NotificationModel model, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //here I'm trying to add flags to my intent
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: Please add all the code that you use to build the `Intent`,  `PendingIntent` and `Notification` to your question.

Comment: Also, using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` should work. How do you know it didn't work? Please run `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` (after you have clicked on the `Notification`) and this will show the actual task stack. Add the output to your question as well.

Comment: Any update on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your Manifest file.

[What it does:](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)

> In this launch mode, if an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the current task, a new instance will not be created and Android system will route the intent information through `onNewIntent()`. If an instance is not present on top of task then new instance will be created.